# linux ubuntu machine webcam taking images and saving them automatically using Cheese

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want to capture images every 5 minutes and save it on my Linux Ubuntu machine. I am using Cheese.
The [page](https://and3k.wordpress.com/2010/02/13/how-to-take-a-picture-every-5-minutes-with-cheese/#comment-627) explains how to capture images. But I need help on saving those images in a particular folder. When images gets saved current timestamp will be the name of those images. How could i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a python script that will take a picture, just setup a loop.

```
import pygame.camera
import datetime
st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
pygame.camera.init()
cam = pygame.camera.Camera(pygame.camera.list_cameras()[0])
cam.start()
img = cam.get_image()
import pygame.image
pygame.image.save(img, st+".bmp")
pygame.camera.quit()
```

ex. filename...

Year-month-day-hour-minute-second.bmp

2015-12-15-01-21-05.bmp